# ASP.NET MVC: Can I say [Authorize Roles="Administrators"] on the Controller class, but have one public action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I started off using the default project's `AccountController`, but I've extended/changed it beyond recognition. However, in common with the original I have a `LogOn` and `LogOff` action.

Clearly, the `LogOn` action must be accessible to everyone. However, since I've added lots of other actions to this controller (to create & edit users), I want 99% of the actions to require administrator role membership.

I could decorate all my actions with `[Authorize Roles="Administrators"]` but there's a risk I'll forget one. I'd rather make it secure by default, by decorating the controller class itself with that attribute, and then relax the requirement on my `LogOn` method. Can I do that?

(As in, can I do that out-of-the-box without creating custom classes, etc. I don't want to complicate things more than necessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override an controller Attribute at the Action level you have to create a custom Attribute and then set the Order property of your custom attribute to a higher value than the controller AuthorizeAttribute.  I believe both attributes are then still executed unless your custom attribute generates a result with immediate effect such as redirecting.

See [Overriding controller AuthorizeAttribute for just one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071235/overriding-controller-authorizeattribute-for-just-one-action) for more information.

So I believe in your case you will just have to add the AuthorizeAttribute on the Actions and not at the controller level.  You could however create a unit test to ensure that all Actions (apart from LogOn) have an AuthorizeAttribute

Answer (score 2):

You can use AuthorizeAttribute on your class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

For relaxing you can implement for example a custom action filter attribute like this (I didn' test if it works).

```
public class GetRidOfAutorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{

// you can for example do nothing
filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult(); 

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After way too much time, I came up with a solution.

```
public class OverridableAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        if(action.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreAuthorization), true)) return;

        var controller = action.ControllerDescriptor;
        if(controller.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreAuthorization), true)) return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Which can be paired with IgnoreAuthorization on an Action

```
public class IgnoreAuthorization : Attribute
{
}
```