# Apply AuthorizeAttribute to a controller class and to action simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

Is There one way to make a [Authorize] attibute be ignored in one action in a controller class that has a Authorize attribute?

```
        [Authorize]
        public class MyController : Controller
        {
           [Authorize(Users="?")]//I tried to do that and with "*", but unsuccessfuly,
           public ActionResult PublicMethod()
           {
           //some code
           }

           public ActionResult PrivateMethod()
           {
           //some code
           }
        }
```

Just the PrivateMethod() should have authentication required, but it has been required too.

PS: I wouldn't like to make my custom authorize filter.

[]'s

Comment: Are you trying to ignore the Authorize that is on class MyController for the action PublicMethod or PrivateMethod?

Comment: It's to ignore for action PublicMethod. I wrote something wrong, I'm sorry, it's fixed now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it's impossible - if you set [Authorize] for controller then only **authenticated** user can access to action.

or

You can try custom decisions: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2537307/303298).

Answer (score 16):

You can use [AllowAnonymous]

```
 [Authorize]
 public class MyController : Controller
 {
     [AllowAnonymous]
     public ActionResult PublicMethod()
     {
           //some code
     }

     public ActionResult PrivateMethod()
     {
           //some code
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution is in this article: [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

The article talks about a white list approach where you decorate actions with a *AllowAnonymous* custom attribute. It requires that you extend `AuthorizeAttribute` and the `OnAuthorization` method to skip authorization checks of *AllowAnonymous* -actions. (The approach is credited to Levi, a security expert on the MVC team.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
       [Authorize] //it will only work for the following action
       public ActionResult PublicMethod()
       {
       //some code
       }

       public ActionResult PrivateMethod()  //[Authorize] will not work for this action
       {
       //some code
       }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding some words to explain your answer.  Answers of just code are normally less helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference This is now available to be done by the the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in ASP.NET MVC 4.

[More Info](https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute)