# If I have defined the [Authorize] attribute at class level is it possible to skip authorisation for one of the actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a base controller class which I want to define `[Authorize]` on as it will be used by every controller in my application. My login screen also uses this base controller but I want to skip authorisation on the login screen so that users can actually log in.

Is it possible to override `OnAuthorization` in just my login controller and pass through whether they are authorised or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding controller AuthorizeAttribute for just one action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071235/overriding-controller-authorizeattribute-for-just-one-action)