# Override AuthorizeAttribute with Policy in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

Using ASP.NET 5 I've implemented a [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) with a requirement that I'd like to apply to most but not all methods within a controller. For the other methods I just want to verify that the current user is authenticated. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to add the `[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]` to each method individually, instead of on the class?

e.g. I'd like this (but I have lots more methods that should be authorized with the policy):

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]
[Route("api/DoStuff")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{ 

    // this one is authorized by MyPolicy, based on the class Authorize attribute
    [HttpGet("foo")]
    public GetFoo() 
    {
    }

    // this one is authorized by MyPolicy, based on the class Authorize attribute
    [HttpGet("bah")]
    public GetBah() 
    {
    }

    // This one I just want to check they're authenticated, not enforce "MyPolicy"
    [Authorize] 
    [HttpGet("anybody")]
    public GetForAnybody() 
    {
    }
}
```

I think in .net webapi I could do this sort of thing with [OverrideAuthorizationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308862(v=vs.118)).

Comment: It's possible by adding custom attributes derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529414/968003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Asp.net Core doesn't support the OverrideAuthorizationAttribute, and it not suggest to override the controller authorize attribute. You can check [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8149).

So, in your scenario, I think the best workaround is change your code as below:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/DoStuff")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{ 

    // this one is authorized by MyPolicy, based on the class Authorize attribute
    [HttpGet("foo")]
    [Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]
    public GetFoo() 
    {
    }

    // this one is authorized by MyPolicy, based on the class Authorize attribute
    [HttpGet("bah")]
    [Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]
    public GetBah() 
    {
    }

    // This one I just want to check they're authenticated, not enforce "MyPolicy"
    //[Authorize]   //since the controller already set the Authorize attribute, there is no need to add it in the action method.
    [HttpGet("anybody")]
    public GetForAnybody() 
    {
    }

    // everybody could access
    [AllowAnonymous]  //By using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, you can restrict the controller and then allow anonymous access to specific actions.
    [HttpGet("everybody")]
    public GetForEverybody() 
    {
    }
}
```